# Relative importance of variables?

Tags: estimation, standard-deviation, standard-error, importance

The following output is given:

[image: t1]

The task is to state, which variables, among thoses that are statistically significnat at 0.05, have the greatest and least relative importance on the fitted model?

**First question**:

I think I have to look at the absolute value of the standardized estimates to get an approximate ranking of the relative importance of the input variables on the fitted model, right?

**Second question**:
How can I calculate these values? I thought about dividing the estimate by the standard error, e.g. $-0.9699/0.0385$ but this is not equal to -0.2074?

Comment: Is this a linear model? You don't mention the model ...